# Offline furigana for iOS

Tags: ios, japanese

Is there any software to compute and display furigana completely offline?

It doesn't have to be integrated with any existing app.  A new standalone app I type into is fine.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/offline-iphone-app-to-recognize-japanese-words?

Comment: No, that question is for OCR (image -> text).  This question is for furigana (kanji -> kana).

Comment: Time to close this one, op never clarified and after 2 years a lot has changed in iOS, no point in reviving every so often.

Comment: We don't close old questions. It's unfortunate when we go without an accepted answer, but if it's on-topic or can be answered due to changes in newer releases of iOS, it's still completely valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have several apps available on the App store now - just search for Furigana.

I have a friend that likes this one, but YMMV:

- Furigana Reader - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/furigana-reader/id529433422?mt=8

It does not work offline, so it doesn't meet your requirements unless you fail to find any offline software and can relax that constraint.

Comment: That app needs an Internet connection to create Furigana from pasted text.

Comment: @TomGewecke On second thought, I messed up. It needs the internet...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused here. You want an app that you can type kanji into and get the kana in return. But the only way to type kanji into the iPhone is by typing it phonetically, which gives you the kana for free, essentially.

There are a number of self-contained Japanese dictionary apps for the iPhone. Most of them use the EDICT dictionary. I've got one that can import EPWING-formatted dictionaries, and have imported Kenkyusha's New Japanese-English Dictionary into it.

[This](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wakaru-read-understand-japanese/id351047145?mt=8) seems like the closest to what you want. I think. I get the impression that it has the dictionaries built-in, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the poster wants something that will add furigana to email or webpage text so he can more easily decipher the kanji.  I think the built in Japanese dictionary could be useful, but it only works in iBooks until we get iOS 5.